# Buy me a coffee/donate links in user profiles

Tags: discussion, external-links

I see that many SO users have buy me a coffee links in their profiles, is this something that one should do? Is this in accord with SO guidelines?

I can't seem to find information about this subject.

Comment: Similar to donate buttons for paypal: [Linking to "PayPal Donate" in your About Me?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265206)

Comment: @Tom yes, it's very similar, didn't find that in my search.